# How to force google chrome sync to update site favicon

Tags: google-chrome, sync, favicon

So here is my problem, I accidentally (still not sure how) changed Google home page favicon to another's site favicon, and now I can't change it back. It's synchronized across all my devices.
So far I tried to open Google page source, and open favicon directly then press refresh. It worked until restart. I also tried to disconnect from chrome sync and delete ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/favicons. Again it worked up until I connected back to sync, then it changed back, to another's site favicon. Is there a way to force chrome sync to update sites favicons?
Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I fixed that by opening Google favicon directly, refreshing the page, and then adding Google home page to the bookmarks. Apparently Chrome sync each time you add a new bookmark.
Later I also discovered **chrome://sync/** where you can manage all you sync data including favicons, so it probably would've helped me too.